# Background-color attribute not working after window is resized

Tags: jquery, html, css

My nav menu is hidden when on smartphone view and can be seen by clicking on a button which adds the class "responsive" to it.
In desktop view, the nav menu is always displayed and changes its background depending on the scrolling as can be seen below.
My issue is that I want a background-color when the nav menu is displayed on smartphone, however if I'm on desktop view then minimize the window down to smartphone-size, the nav menu has no background. To get it I need to refresh the page.

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if(!$(".site-nav").hasClass("responsive")){
        $(".site-nav").css("top",Math.max(-10,130-$(this).scrollTop()));

        var wn = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(wn > 130){
            $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(225,225,225,0.7)");
        }
        else{
            $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
        }
      }
      });
  });
```

//responsive site-nav

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".icon").click(function(){
        if ($(".site-nav").hasClass("responsive")) {
          $(".site-nav").removeClass("responsive");
        } else {
          $(".site-nav").addClass("responsive");
        }
      });
  });
```

CSS:

```
.site-nav.responsive {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
}
```

EDIT:
the background-color disappears because somehow even when it's responsive (after resizing from smartphone-size) it goes to those lines:

```
    else{
            $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true you need to use `.resize()` check this below example, scale that front and back to see change of background-color,

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var wd = $(window).width();
  if (wd <= 640) {
    $("#menu").css("background", "blue");
  } else if (wd >= 641) {
    $("#menu").css("background", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">

</div>
```

[jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rnt3wpu5/)

Comment: @Twister013 You could use jQuery or media query to do this as you added your nav is hidden and visible when click on button, so both works.

Comment: Thanks! What I did is add `.removeAttr("style")` inside the `.resize()` and now I have everything I wanted. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome @Twister013 that's great :-), that would have even worked if you might have add or removed class.

Answer (score 2):

You can check with javascript/jquery if the window resizes

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //resize just happened
});
```

Comment: The window resize works because the rest of my CSS is alright (the display changes completely). The only thing causing an issue is this background. Thanks though!